# Why the default type of the label is a forced unwrapped optional?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel, option-type

When I create a **label** in the **view** (dragged from the Object library) and make the **IBOutlet** to connect the **label** and **viewController** (Ctrl and drag), The default code generated by Xcode is, for example, `@IBOutlet weak var displayColumn: UILabel!`

I can delete the exclamation mark and set it as the `UILable` only. But there must be a good reason the Xcode want it to be a forced unwrapped optional type.

**Question**: I don't think I understand the reason to use the optional type here. Because I already created a label in my view and connected it to my controller, it is firmly out there, it exists, I created it. Why Xcode want an option as the default type? If it says the text inside the label is an option, that sounds reasonable to me, because the label may be empty at some point in run time.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have created a label in Xcode and indicated to Xcode that you want that label connected to that `@IBOutlet`.  But that connection doesn't happen until later.

This is the order of events at runtime.

1. The viewController is created (instantiated).
2. The Storyboard or .xib is unarchived.  The label is created at this time.
3. The `@IBOutlet`s and `@IBAction`s are connected.

In Swift, when a class is instantiated, all properties must be initialized.  In step 1, the outlets are `nil` because they haven't been connected yet.  In order to allow for this, they must be declared as *Optionals*.

It is perfectly valid to use a normal *Optional*, such as:

```
@IBOutlet weak var displayColumn: UILabel?
```

but then you'd have to deal with unwrapping it each time you access it.  The only time an `@IBOutlet` will be nil is when step 3 hasn't happened yet (for example, in `prepareForSegue`) or if you forgot to connect the outlet or renamed it.  In those cases, the crash caused by accessing `nil` alerts you to the problem.

Comment: Thaks you so much. Very nice explanation, clear and solid!